# ERROR: LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI MEDIA

Tags: software-installation, error-handling

I recently built my first custom PC and, instead paying for Windows right off the bat, I decided I wanted to install Ubuntu first.

I got the PC started up with no problem, downloaded Ubuntu earlier today--no issues. But, when I plugged the USB into the PC it gave me the error I wrote in the title.

Again, I have added no other software just yet. Do I have to install Windows first, or is there a way of bypassing/correcting the error?

I've watched videos and read countless articles about the error, but everyone with a fix already had Windows installed prior to Ubuntu.

What am I doing/not doing?

Comment: Windows is not required; let's try again. Download the ISO file for the version of your choice at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a different 'flavour', download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO used to make a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Comment: Making the Live USB to install from can be done on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 . Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: Open BIOS setup and make sure UEFI is turned on.